# How to disable a checkbox when a second checkbox is checked?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form and it has 2 checkboxes and a text input.

If I select the 1st checkbox, then the 2nd checkbox should be disabled and if I select 2nd checkbox, then the 1st checkbox should be disabled.

In other words, only one checkbox should be checked at a time.

The task I'm doing requires that I use checkboxes (instead of radio buttons), so I have tried the following solution:

```js
function sub() {
  var text = document.getElementById("text");
  var ret = true;
  if (text == null) {
    document.getElementById("txtErr").innerHTML = "please enter a text";
    ret = false;
  } else document.getElementById("txtErr").innerHTML = "";
  return ret;
}

function enable() {
  var giga = document.getElementById("gigamonenable");
  var m2k = document.getElementById("m2000enable");

  if (giga.checked == true || m2k.checked == true) {
    if (giga.checked == true) {
      document.getElementById("m2000enable").disabled = true;
      document.getElementById("gigamonenable").disabled = false;
    } else if (m2k.checked == true) {
      document.getElementById("gigamonenable").disabled = true;
      document.getElementById("m2000enable").disabled = false;
    }
  }
```

```html
<form action="abc.html" onsubmit="return sub()">
  <input type="checkbox" id="gigamonenable" name="gigamonenable" onchange="enable()" /> Gigamon port Enable
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="m2000enable" name="m2000enable" onchange="enable()" /> M2000 port Enable
  <br>
  <input type="text" id="text" /><span id="txtErr" class="error"></span>
  <input type="submit" id="submit" /><br>
  <br>
</form>
```

Comment: So...what's your question?

Comment: out of 2 check boxes ,if i checked one check box another check box should be disabled
@TorbjörnStabo

Comment: This seems like a long-winded way to reinvent radio buttons with a UI that confuses people more.

Comment: if you disable the second checkbox on selecting first one how would you select it again? it is disabled isn't it?

Comment: if i want to select second check box which is already in disable i must need to uncheck  the first check box @sandeepjoshi

Comment: got it...@HarishNune

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function enable() {
    var giga = document.getElementById("gigamonenable");
    var m2k = document.getElementById("m2000enable");
    if (giga.checked == true) {
        m2k.checked = false;
        m2k.disabled = true;
    } else if (m2k.checked == true) {
        giga.checked = false;
        giga.disabled = true;
    } else {
        m2k.disabled = false;
        giga.disabled = false;
    }
}
```

```html
<form action="abc.html" onsubmit="return sub()">
  <input type="checkbox" id="gigamonenable" name="gigamonenable" onchange="enable()" /> Gigamon port Enable
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="m2000enable" name="m2000enable" onchange="enable()" /> M2000 port Enable
  <br>
  <input type="text" id="text" /><span id="txtErr" class="error"></span>
  <input type="submit" id="submit" /><br>
  <br>
</form>
```